# Show all fields in Views in IBM Domino Designer

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, domino-designer-eclipse

I have to add a particular field in a view in my IBM Domino Designer, but I do not find it.

There are part of my forms :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdGf6.png

So I want to show a column with the field "Procédure", i went in my view but "Procédure" don't show up.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOAAf.png

As you can see, "NUM_RG" show up but "Procédure" don't.
How I can add a column with "Procédure" field ?

PS : I do not make the forms or anything else in this document.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that Acute accent is allowed in field names?

Test switching to formula and write procédure there

Otherwise:

Try renaming the field to procedure instead of procédure if possible and see if it is in listing

Answer (score 0):

Procédure is a valid name, but it is a rich text field and Rich Text fields cannot be used in a view column. You can add a computed text field to the form with a formula using @Abstract(...) if you want to show part of the contents of the field Procédure.

Comment: that's what i found about this morning after searching. I see now the computed field for column but it show nothing in the view, I must be missing something

Comment: The field just cannot be used in a column, it is impossible in a standard view in Notes. You'd have to create a new field on the form, computed, with a formula like @Abstract([TextOnly]; 100; ""; Procédure). Plus, you'd have to write an agent to update all documents, so that the new text field is created on existing documents. Désolé...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the agent updater, I am trying to do it but I can not update the document with it. I've followed (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-display-rich-text-field-information-notes-view) but I got a message "@command and other ui functions are not allowed with this search type". I'm stuck here.

Comment: Maybe it works when you select None as target for your agent. Otherwise, you have to set your field using a formula. It should be: Field TxtProcédure:= @Abstract([TextOnly]; 100; ""; Procédure)

Comment: If I put None as target, 0 documents are modified. If I put your formula in my formula fields, it throw an error "No main or selection expression in formula: ')'"

Comment: Sorry, None as target for your code using @Command... My formula needs to run in an agent that runs On selected documents.

Comment: Same things happens, I have an error with your formula : https://reho.st/self/24bdfee27c5a209e70fb869667ba5cf273d3e841.png

Comment: Small change: Field TxtProcédure:= @Abstract([TextOnly]; 100; ""; "Procédure")

Comment: And there's a strange thing: the Designer Client seems to want a 5th parameter to that function, "pars", but I have no clue as to why...